# does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix it in react native

Tags: react-native, video

so I am working on this react native project and I am using an external api and in the api there is (for some) items a link to a video so when I do npm start and I wanna view the video for an item the whole app crashes and I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in Video (created by CuisinesRecipeDetail)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by CuisinesRecipeDetail)
    in CuisinesRecipeDetail (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

this is how the video code looks

```
 {recipevideo ? (
        <Video
          source={{
            uri: recipevideo,
          }}
          controls={true} // Show playback controls
          paused={true} // Start playing the video
          onError={(error) => console.error("Video Error:", error)}
          style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }} // You can adjust the dimensions
        />
      ) : null}
```

```
this is the whole code 

    import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Video from "react-native-video";

export default function RecipeDetail({ route }) {
  let {
    recipeName,
    recipeDescription,
    ingredientLines,
    imageUrl,
    preperationsteps,
    recipevideo,
  } = route.params;
  let playerRef = useRef(null);
  console.log(recipevideo);

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {imageUrl && <Image source={{ uri: imageUrl }} style={styles.image} />}
      <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe Details for: {recipeName}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.description}>Description: {recipeDescription}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ingredientsTitle}>Ingredients:</Text>
      {ingredientLines.map((ingredientLine, index) => (
        <Text style={styles.ingredientLine} key={index}>
          {ingredientLine.ingredient}:{" "}
          {ingredientLine.wholeLine ? (
            ingredientLine.wholeLine
          ) : (
            <Text>
              {ingredientLine.quantity} {ingredientLine.unit}{" "}
              {ingredientLine.ingredient} {ingredientLine.remainder}
            </Text>
          )}
        </Text>
      ))}
      <Text style={styles.ingredientsTitle}>Preparation Steps</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ingredientLine}>
        {preperationsteps ? (
          preperationsteps
        ) : (
          <Text
            style={{ color: "blue" }}
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(preplink)}
          >
            Link to recipe prependition steps
          </Text>
        )}
      </Text>
      {recipevideo ? (
        <Video
          source={{
            uri: recipevideo,
          }}
          controls={true} // Show playback controls
          paused={true} // Start playing the video
          onError={(error) => console.error("Video Error:", error)}
          style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }} // You can adjust the dimensions
        />
      ) : null}

      {/* Add more details about the recipe here */}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

but if I run the app with this npx react-native run-ios I don't get the error and the video plays no problem

Comment: Can you make it clear: How do you got the error?

Comment: Error message is pretty clear: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined* You are trying to access `Constants` from an object which is `undefined`

Comment: can you share the complete code of the  CuisinesRecipeDetail

Comment: @DinhNguyen when I press on a recipe it should take me to this page that has all the info and one of them is a video and if the that recipe has a video once I click on it the app crashes and I get the error

Comment: @DecPK I added the whole code for that page not sure what constant exactly, thanks

Comment: @FaysalB I added it

Answer (score 0):

If you are on newest version of react-native-video, make sure to follow newest linking procedure for Android installation.

```
const VideoPlayer = () => {
 const videoRef = useRef<VideoRef>(null);
 const background = require('./background.mp4');

 return (
   <Video 
    // Can be a URL or a local file.
    source={background}
    // Store reference  
    ref={videoRef}
    // Callback when remote video is buffering                                      
    onBuffer={onBuffer}
    // Callback when video cannot be loaded              
    onError={onError}               
    style={styles.backgroundVideo}
   />
 )
}
```

Follow [this](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#android-installation) for more info